# How to organize objects to render

Tags: c++, opengl, wavefront

I want to render an object imported from wavefront obj file. The object has multiple groups and materials:

```
# group one
g one
v ...
vt ...
vn ...
# material A
usemtl ...
f ...
# material B
usemtl ...
f ..

# second group
g two
v ...
vt ...
vn ...
# material C
usemtl ...
f ...
# material D
usemtl ...
f ...
```

The different parts of the model need to be rendered separately, as they have different materials.

I will build a container with an information about the model and I would like to know what is the best/common way to organize the "queue" of the objects to render.

My idea, which I don't know if it's good is the following (with pseudocode): for each group `g` store all vertex information in object `VertexInformation g1, g2` and for each `usemtl` store information about faces (and the used material) in `FaceInformation f1, f2, f3, f4`.

Then the rendering would look as follows:

```
load vertices g1
render f1 f2
load vertices g2
render f3 f4
```

Or maybe better to load all the vertices from `g1` and `g2` at once?

Is that the way? Or it has some giant drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would to suggest you to declare the interface IModel and implement it in a different models like WavefrontModel so:

```
class IModel{
public:
 virtual bool drawModel() =0;
};

class WavefrontModel : public IModel{
public:
  bool drawModel();
};
```

I have an example for you here:
http://code.google.com/p/gstmultimedialib/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fgstmultimedialib%2FGLEngine%2FGLEngine%2FModel

If you want you can get the glEngine module from this project.

After that implement your scene or device which will contain a list of your models.

```
class Device{
private:
 std::list< IModel* > m_models;

public:
 bool drawScene(); //iterate all of your models and call the draw method here.
};
```